# Is there some clashes between rasterio and shapely?

Tags: python, python-import, python-xarray, shapely, rasterio

I try to use natcap.invest module which needs **shapely** module, and also use **rasterio** module in my project. It can work successfully if I just import natcap.invest module. But it seems cannot work if I import natcap.invest and rasterio **at the same time**.

[case1] When I import rasterio **before** I run the main code, it reports when running the main code:  GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer.

[case2] When I import rasterio **after** I run the main code successfully, it reports when importing rasterio module: ImportError: DLL load failed: the given module is not found.

The code is as the following:

```
import logging
import sys
import numpy as np
import natcap.invest.hydropower.hydropower_water_yield
import natcap.invest.utils

import xarray as xr
import rasterio                      # case 1



# main code
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=natcap.invest.utils.LOG_FMT,
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S ')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, handlers=[handler])

args = {
    'biophysical_table_path': 'F:/biophysical_table_gura.csv',
    'depth_to_root_rest_layer_path': 'F:/depth_to_root_restricting_layer_gura.tif',
    'do_scarcity_and_valuation': False,
    'eto_path': 'F:/reference_ET_gura.tif',
    'lulc_path': 'F:/land_use_gura.tif',
    'pawc_path': 'F:/plant_available_water_fraction_gura.tif',
    'precipitation_path': 'F:/precipitation_gura.tif',
    'results_suffix': 'temp1',
    'seasonality_constant': '5',
    'sub_watersheds_path': '',
    'watersheds_path': 'F:/watershed_gura.shp',
    'workspace_dir': 'F:/OUTPUT',
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    natcap.invest.hydropower.hydropower_water_yield.execute(args)     # where error of case 1 occurs.




import rasterio                   # case 2     # where error of case 2 occurs.
```

Is there any solution that I can import and use these two modules at the same time successfully?

Comment: I guess the main reason is the incompatibility of rasterio and shapely, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be problems if the two modules import different versions of the GEOS library. Ensure that you install both modules from the same source, or build them from source against the same GEOS library.

More information on how to do this is given in the documentation: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project.html#installing-shapely

> ### Built distributions
>
> Built distributions are the only option for users who do not have or
> do not know how to use their platform’s compiler and Python SDK, and a
> good option for users who would rather not bother.
>
> Linux, OS X, and Windows users can get Shapely wheels with GEOS
> included from the Python Package Index with a recent version of pip
> (8+):
>
> `$ pip install shapely`
>
> Shapely is available via system package management tools like apt,
> yum, and Homebrew, and is also provided by popular Python
> distributions like Canopy and Anaconda. If you use the Conda package
> manager to install Shapely, be sure to use the conda-forge channel.
>
> Windows users have another good installation options: the wheels
> published at [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely).
> These can be installed using pip by specifying the entire URL.
>
> #### Source distributions
>
> If you want to build Shapely from source for compatibility with other
> modules that depend on GEOS (such as cartopy or osgeo.ogr) or want to
> use a different version of GEOS than the one included in the project
> wheels you should first install the GEOS library, Cython, and Numpy on
> your system (using apt, yum, brew, or other means) and then direct pip
> to ignore the binary wheels.
>
> `$ pip install shapely --no-binary shapely`
>
> If you’ve installed GEOS to a standard location, the geos-config
> program will be used to get compiler and linker options. If
> geos-config is not on your executable, it can be specified with a
> GEOS_CONFIG environment variable, e.g.:
>
> `$ GEOS_CONFIG=/path/to/geos-config pip install shapely`